# Select previous record in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have this syntax sql who catches the record whose id is equal to what I set:

```
SELECT * FROM table one WHERE id = '128'
```

So I select the previous record by id I could just take that number and subtract by 1 (128-1 = 127), but we assume that the record 127 is excluded from the table? In this case he would select an id that does not exist.

How I can change my syntax sql to select previous record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table one
WHERE id < 128
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Or, if you just want the `id`:

```
SELECT MAX(id)
FROM table one
WHERE id < 128;
```